# Only little record can I insert in to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I tried to import 200,000 records from Excel to SQL Server 2005 using ASP.NET with C#. But when I try to browse and import the file, only few records are inserted (100 records only). I could not get any solution.

Here is my sample code

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



public partial class UploadExcel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
///***when the button press, this code will execute***
    protected void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int count = 0;          
        try
        {
            string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/TempFiles/"), UploadExcel1.FileName);
            //Save File as Temp then you can delete it if you want
            UploadExcel1.SaveAs(path);
            DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
            string SourceConstr = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0",path);
            OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(SourceConstr);
            string query = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";
            OleDbDataAdapter dataadapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(query,con1);
            dataadapt.Fill(dtExcel);
            ///connection string with in the database below
            string sqlconn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["zena"].ToString();
            //all the excel file is stored in the data table here
            for (int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Rows.Count;  i++)
            {
               try
               {
                  SqlConnection sconn = new SqlConnection(sqlconn);
                  sconn.Open();
                  string insert_query12 = "insert into FCROperation (CallingNumber,OperatorId,OperatorName,CallReason) values("+dtExcel.Rows[i][0]+","+dtExcel.Rows[i][1]+",'"+dtExcel.Rows[i][2]+"','"+dtExcel.Rows[i][3]+"')";

                  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_query12,sconn);
                  count+=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();            
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   //continue;             
                }
                //Label1.Text = ex.Message;
             }
            if (count == dtExcel.Rows.Count)
            {
               Label1.Text = "Success" + dtExcel.Rows.Count + count;
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Failed" + dtExcel.Rows.Count + count;
                //Label1 = dtExcel.Rows.Count;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Label1.Text = ex.Message;
           //throw ex;        
        }
        finally
        {              
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your excel cell is null you must apply DBNull.Value value.

Comment: dear thank you for your valuable support, my excel is full of record and possible to insert null value in to the table.

Comment: how did you confirm that only 100 records are inserted? Did you use SELECT COUNT(*) or right clicked on table and opened in edit mode. Because, in edit mode SSMS displays 100 records only by default.

Comment: give me dtExcel.Rows.Count result...

Comment: (As test) change this: count+=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); in int k = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), then go in debug and check when k = 0. In this way you can get the problematic row, then post here

Comment: Use a list(`Dictonary<int, Exception>`) outside for loop and into `Catch` block and add `i, ex` into this list to get all the rows causing exception

Comment: as i know excel capacity is only 65000 rows, how you added 200000 rows to excel?

Comment: i were used <select * from TableName> command to check the entered records. and the value of <dtExcel.Rows.Count> is number of records in the excel.

Comment: i know excel capacity is 1048576 rows and 16384 columns

Answer (score 1):

I want ot recommend you to open connection only one time, not each time when you insert a row

```
using (SqlConnection sconn = new SqlConnection(sqlconn))
{
  sconn.Open();
  for (int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Rows.Count;  i++)
            {
               try
               {                                 
                  string insert_query12 = "insert into FCROperation (CallingNumber,OperatorId,OperatorName,CallReason) values("+dtExcel.Rows[i][0]+","+dtExcel.Rows[i][1]+",'"+dtExcel.Rows[i][2]+"','"+dtExcel.Rows[i][3]+"')";
                  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_query12,sconn);
                  count+=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();            
                }
             catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
               {
                errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                    "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                    "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                    "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                    "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
               }
               Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());
            }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   //continue;             
                }
                //Label1.Text = ex.Message;
             }
}
```

Comment: Dear, I tried to implement your recommendation, but oly 16 records going to be inserted.<dtExcel.Rows.Count> is as exact as the number of records in the excel. but <Count> is only have 16 values.

Comment: My answer was about your approach to work with DB. Please check, I updated my answer so you may see all exceptions which occur in sql during execution INSERT. Analise of those errors you may understand why only couple of rows were inserted. I also want to wonder you that ExecuteNonQuery returns -1 if transaction was rollback. So you count not amunt of all inserted rows, but amount of inserted rows - rollback transactions

Answer (score 0):

Replace your for loop code with this one to track all the rows causing exception. And add a breakpoint after the loop to inspect `errors`

```
Dictonary<int, Exception> errors = new Dictonary<int, Exception>();
for (int i = 0; i < dtExcel.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
      try
      {
          SqlConnection sconn = new SqlConnection(sqlconn);
          sconn.Open();
          string insert_query12 = "insert into FCROperation (CallingNumber,OperatorId,OperatorName,CallReason) values("+dtExcel.Rows[i][0]+","+dtExcel.Rows[i][1]+",'"+dtExcel.Rows[i][2]+"','"+dtExcel.Rows[i][3]+"')";

          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert_query12,sconn);
          count+=cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
            errors.Add(i, ex);
            //continue;

      }
      //Label1.Text = ex.Message;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Excel OLE DB driver is only finding the first 100 rows of the spreadsheet.  This could be due to a variety of reasons.  For example, here is [one user who found that the Excel print area affected the driver](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b15aa89-d5e2-4aca-a026-c55d013e4db2/oledbconnection-not-reading-all-data-from-excel?forum=vbgeneral).  I suggest you cut and paste the Excel data into a fresh spreadsheet with minimum formatting and see if the situation improves.